# MongoDB - Mongoose data from two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know what I need and how to write it in SQL. But I have MongoDB and using Mongoose.

SQL query is:

```
select c.name o.person
from cofee c inner join order o
on c.id = o.cofee;
```

How could this be solved in MEAN stack?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an input example and expected output?

Comment: In database I have collection of cofees and another of orders. I need on the front-end data from orders, but id of cofee replaced with name of cofee.